# Is there any way to get few fields from nested records of beam pipeline?

Tags: python, apache-beam

I'm reading an Avro file, which is having nested schema with too many fields. for example : employeeId, empName, empPersonalInfo.Address.city etc. I want to write a parDo function to get only few fields from pipeline records(employeeId, empPersonalInfo.Address.city)

```
schema of an avro file is :
{
     "namespace"    : "studentjoin.avro",
     "type"         : "record",
     "name"         : "student",
     "fields"       : [
      {"name": "personalInfo",
       "type": { "type" : "array", "items": { 
           "type" : "record",                                
               "name" : "studentinfo",
           "fields": [
                 {"name": "studentId", "type": "int"},
                 {"name": "studentName",  "type": ["string", "null"]},
                 {"name": "studentAddress", "type": {
                    "type" : "array", "items" : {
                        "type": "record", "name" : "addressInfo", 
                        "fields":
                         [
                            {"name" : "streetName", "type": ["string", "null"] },
                            {"name": "city", "type": ["string","null"]}
                         ] }}},

                 {"name": "studentBranch", "type": ["string", "null"]}
                 ]
        } }
    }

    ]
}
```

if there are no nested fields than below runs perfectly:

```
fields_of_interest = (p | 'Projected' >> beam.Map( 
          lambda row: {f: row[f] for f in selected_fileld_names}))
```

There is unnest builtin function in java SDk, which first convert all nested fields on one level, if same kind of the things possible in python than it will be helpful.

Comment: It would be useful if you could provide some sample data, or at least the format of the data, as well as whatever code you're currently using to read/process the file.

Comment: source_record =  p | 'Read file' >> beam.io.avroio.ReadFromAvro(input_file)

Comment: Try to use a DoFn to test the way you get the data from your object. That'd be more suitable than doing that in a Map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pl = (pl |
      "Extract" >> beam.Map(lambda x:
         (x["student"]["personalInfo"][0]["studentInfo"]["studentId"], x["student"]["personalInfo"][0]["studentInfo"]["studentAddress"][0]["addressInfo"]))
```

You can't simply flatten the dictionary, it contains lists (specified by the `'type':'array'`, which means there's different ways to flatten it. What if there are multiple addresses (whith multiple city names)? Return the first, or all? In the implementation above, it returns only the first element.